# Prediction percentage come wrong(Logical error)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, artificial-intelligence, prediction

In the code below I was trying to predict the probability of diabetes. At the section that I want to calculate the percentage of true an false in the data frame and the code for this duty seems to be correct but it gives wrong output.

Input:

number of true: 268

number of false: 500

Expected output:

true: 34.90%-------false: 65.10%

34.90 + 65.10 =100.00

what I get:

true: 34.90%-------false: 50.00%

34.90 + 50.00 != 100

which is wierd! cause we have only True and False(50%,50%)

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
​
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('pima-data-Copy1.csv')


df.isnull().values.any()

dibetes_map = {True:1, False:0}
df['diabetes'] = df['diabetes'].map(dibetes_map)

num_true = len(df.loc[df['diabetes'] == True])
num_false = len(df.loc[df['diabetes'] == False])
​
print("number of true: {0} ({1:2.2f}%)".format(num_true, (num_true/(num_true + num_false))*100))
print("number of false: {0} ({1:2.2f}%)".format(num_false, (num_false/(num_false + num_false))*100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `num_false + num_false` in the denominator in the second line. Below are some suggested simplications:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pima-data-Copy1.csv')

# df.isnull().values.any()  this isn't used anywhere

# dibetes_map = {True:1, False:0}   
# df['diabetes'] = df['diabetes'].map(dibetes_map)   # this is redundant as you are comparing with True/False

num_true = df['diabetes'].sum()
total = df['diabetes'].count()
num_false = total - num_true 

print("number of true: {0} ({1:2.2f}%)".format(num_true, (num_true / total)*100))
print("number of false: {0} ({1:2.2f}%)".format(num_false, (num_false / total)*100)))
```